# How can I understand ATT estimator for matching discrepancies in Causal Inference Mixtape?

Tags: causality, bias, matching, bias-correction

While studying 'Causal Inference: Mixtape' by myself, something I didn't know happened.

link: https://mixtape.scunning.com/matching-and-subclassification.html#bias-correction

$\begin{align}    \widehat{\delta}_{ATT} - \delta_{ATT}
      & = \dfrac{1}{N_T} \sum_{D_i=1} \left( \mu^1(X_i) - {\mu^0(X_i)} - \delta_{ATT}\right)     \\
      & + \dfrac{1}{N_T} \sum_{D_i=1} (\varepsilon_i - \varepsilon_{j(i)})                       \\
      & + \dfrac{1}{N_T} \sum_{D_i=1} \left( {\mu^0(X_i)} - \mu^0(X_{j(i)}) \right).          \end{align}$

> Now consider the implications if the number of covariates is large.
> First, the difference between $X_i$ and $X_{j(i)}$ converges to zero slowly.
> This therefore makes the difference $\mu^0(X_i) - \mu(X_{j(i)})$ converge to zero very slowly.
> Third, $E[ \sqrt{N_T} (\mu^0(X_i) - \mu^0(X_{j(i)}))\mid D=1]$ may not converge to zero.
> And fourth, $E[ \sqrt{N_T} (\widehat{\delta}_{ATT} - \delta_{ATT})]$ may not converge to zero.

(1) How can I get first term to zero?

- $\dfrac{1}{N_T} \sum_{D_i=1} \left( \mu^1(X_i) - {\mu^0(X_i)} - \delta_{ATT}\right)$

(2) How can I understand it?

- Third, $E[ \sqrt{N_T} (\mu^0(X_i) - \mu^0(X_{j(i)}))\mid D=1]$ may not converge to zero.

Reference

(1) $D$: Treatment, $X$: Covariates, $Y$: Output

(2) $\begin{align}
   \mu^0(x) & = E\big[Y\mid X=x, D=0\big] = E\big[Y^0\mid X=x\big] \\
   \mu^1(x) & = E\big[Y\mid X=x, D=1\big] = E\big[Y^1\mid X=x\big] 
\end{align}$

(3) A simple matching estimator is the following:
$\widehat{\delta}_{ATT} = \dfrac{1}{N_T} \sum_{D_i=1}(Y_i - Y_{j(i)})$
where $Y_{j(i)}$ is the j th unit matched to the  i th unit based on the  j th being “closest to” the  i th unit for some $X$ covariate. For instance, let’s say that a unit in the treatment group has a covariate with a value of 2 and we find another unit in the control group (exactly one unit) with a covariate value of 2. Then we will impute the treatment unit’s missing counterfactual with the matched unit’s, and take a difference.

link: https://mixtape.scunning.com/matching-and-subclassification.html#exact-matching